# Spring batch launches SimpleJobLauncher run method before boot run method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have job configuration as below

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Test implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    Job job;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Test.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(job, params);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that when i run this Test application, SimpleJobLauncher launches run method before JobParameters are created. From logs

```
10:12:58.422 - [    main] - INFO  SimpleJobLauncher                        - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=demoJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
10:12:58.466 - [    main] - INFO  SimpleStepHandler                        - Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute: StepExecution: id=14, version=3, name=stepOne, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
10:12:58.478 - [    main] - INFO  SimpleStepHandler                        - Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute: StepExecution: id=15, version=3, name=stepTwo, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
10:12:58.498 - [    main] - INFO  SimpleJobLauncher                        - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=demoJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 44ms
10:12:58.530 - [    main] - INFO  SimpleJobLauncher                        - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=demoJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{JobID=1592381578499}]
```

As you can see from the logs first demoJob is launched with no parameters

```
10:12:58.422 - [    main] - INFO  SimpleJobLauncher                        - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=demoJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
```

After finishing job with no parameters the it launches again with parameters.

```
10:12:58.530 - [    main] - INFO  SimpleJobLauncher                        - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=demoJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{JobID=1592381578499}]
```

Lets say if there two jobs in application, then both jobs are launched eventhough i want to run a specific one with specified parameters
Is there anyway to control this behaviour so Spring batch only launches only job with parameters i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable automatic execution of jobs at startup by adding a property to application.yml or application.properties

```
spring.batch.job.enabled: false
```

Comment: You mean disable it in integration tests, use the same property spring.batch.job.enabled: false and put it in an application.yml or application.properties in the src/test/resources directory of your project

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple jobs, you will have to define multiple Job beans in your batch configurations. You can autowire both Job beans, then based on a parameter you can execute pass correct bean to run()

```
@Autowired
private Job importUserJob;

@Autowired
private Job syncUserJob;

if (jobNameArgument.equals("importUserJob")){
        jobLauncher.run(importUserJob, params);
}else {
        jobLauncher.run(syncUserJob, params);
}
```