# Spring Boot calling Spring Batch Job

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Below is my sequence

Spring Boot main class has run() method which in turn calls spring batch job.

when i execute above main class it executes the job first and then later executes my run() method.

If i disable the job , run() method executes first.

is there any way i can execute run()method first and then later call job.

Spring boot with run

MemberTaskletsApplication{
has  some create statements
}
SpringApplication.run(MemberTaskletsApplication.class, args);

batch job class
public class ReadWriteBatchImpl {

has reader/writer methods

}

Thank you

Comment: Pl note im using CommandLineRunner in above scenario

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: My requirement is to call CommandLineRunner before JobLauncherApplicationRunner, currently when i run as java application, JobLauncherApplicationRunner is starting by default and then later it executes my run() method. i wanted run first and then job launcher later. Pl note job launcher is calling SimpleJobLauncher.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.2.0.M1/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java   ---i can see from logs..  line 115 is causing this..how do i workaround??? im new to spring boot and batch...any inputs appreciated.

Comment: this is exact issue i have but solution doesn't help ....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62424538/spring-batch-launches-simplejoblauncher-run-method-before-boot-run-method